# Proving solution to linear parabolic PDE is convex with negative third derivative

Tags: convexity, parabolic-pde

I have a PDE in $g(y,t)$ of the form
\begin{equation}
a\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial y^2}y^2-b\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}y -rg + \frac{\partial g}{\partial t} - c = 0
\end{equation}
in which $a$, $b$, $c$, and $r$ are positive constants and $(y,t) \in [0,\infty) \times [0,T]$. Boundary conditions are 
\begin{align}
g(0,t) = k_1e^{-r(T-t)}-k_2 \\ 
\lim_{y \to \infty} g(y,t) = k_2\left(e^{-r(T-t)}-1\right) \\
g(y,T) = \psi(y) 
\end{align}
where $k_1>k_2>0$, $\frac{d\psi}{dy}<0$, $\frac{d^2\psi}{dy^2}>0$, and $\frac{d^3\psi}{dy^3}<0$.

I'm pretty convinced that $\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial y^2} > 0$ and $\frac{\partial^3g}{\partial y^3} < 0$, i.e. those properties propagate from the terminal boundary condition, but I don't know how to prove it. I'd appreciate any ideas.

Ultimately, I'm trying to show that 
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial y^2}\right)^2y < \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\right)\left(\frac{\partial^3g}{\partial y^3}\right)y + \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\right)\left(\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial y^2}\right)
\end{equation}

Do you think there's any hope?

(In my original post I expressed the PDE in terms of a different function,
\begin{equation}
f(x,t) = \left(g(y,t)+\frac{c}{r}\right)e^{r(T-t)}
\end{equation}
where $y = e^x$. Making this substitution transforms the PDE to $a\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} - (a+b)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = 0$, which is linear parabolic and easier to work with. Sorry for the mix-up.)

---

Above is the parsimonious version--figuring that out will be sufficient for what I want to do, but the full problem I'm studying is a little more involved. It's a PDE with two moving boundaries:

\begin{equation}
\max_{u_1,u_2} \left[ \left( a_1u_1+a_2u_2+a_3\sqrt{u_1u_2}+a_4 \right)\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial y^2}y^2 - (b_1u_1+b_2u_2+b_3)\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}y - (u_1+u_2)+\frac{\partial g}{\partial t} - rg \right] = 0
\end{equation}

where all constants $a$, $b$, and $r$ are positive. The decision variables $u_i$ are functions of $y$ and $t$, and there is a "budget constraint" such that $0 \leq u_1+u_2\leq q$. The (non-moving) boundary conditions are

\begin{align}
g(0,t) = ke^{-r(T-t)} \\ 
\lim_{y \to \infty} g(y,t) = 0 \\
g(y,T) = \psi(y) 
\end{align}
where again $\frac{d\psi}{dy}<0$, $\frac{d^2\psi}{dy^2}>0$, and $\frac{d^3\psi}{dy^3}<0$.

Analysis shows that the two moving boundaries take the form $C_l(t)$ and $C_u(t)$, where for $0 \leq y < C_l(t)$ or $y \geq C_u(t)$, $u_1=u_2=0$, and for $C_l(t) \leq y < C_u(t)$, $u_1+u_2 = q$. I've derived equations for $u_1$ and $u_2$ as functions of $g$ and its derivatives and I'm trying to prove results on the sensitivities of $u_1$ and $u_2$ to different parameters (the motivating problem is R&D investment strategies, where $u_1$ and $u_2$ represent investment in high-risk research and low-risk development to lower the cost of a technology). This is why I'm trying to show $\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial y^2}>0$ and $\frac{\partial^3g}{\partial y^3}<0$, and the additional result, especially within the region defined by the two moving boundaries. Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: Your boundary conditions for $x\to\pm\infty$ show that $f$ cannot be convex in $x$. A convex function cannot behave like this.

Comment: Actually, the boundary condition at $-\infty$ is not fully stated. Maybe the limit that is equal to k is the limit of $f_{xx}$ rather than f?

Comment: You're right @AlexandreEremenko, I had stated boundary conditions for a PDE of a transformed function, not $f$. I've fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: the equation cannot be linear unless $c=0$.

Comment: your equation contains the Black-Scholes equation as a special case (if $b=-r$). the B-S equation can be solved explicitly*. why don't you test your conjecture on that special formula?

*well, at least for *homogeneous* Dirichlet boundary conditions, whereas yours are inhomogeneous; but there are of course standard ways to derive a solution of the inhomogeneous problem from the solution of the homogeneous one.

Comment: Is it proven that such a solution exist? Is $\psi$ given or to be taken s.t. a solution should exist?

Comment: $\psi$ is given. In my numerical example, $\psi(y) = \max(k-y,0)$. (I could also tweak the problem such that $\psi$ is a different, strictly nonnegative, convex function with a uniformly negative first derivative. I think I could also assume $\psi$ is logarithmically convex, if that would help.)

Comment: At least in the linear case the Cauchy problem for parabolic equation is determined by the initial function. No separate conditions on infinity are imposed, except to guarantee the uniqueness of solutions. Say the solution is sought in the class of bounded functions. Why here solution wouldn't be determined completely by the initial function?